# Why is userName a required property for envelopeViews?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm not sure if this is a bug. But I discovered this in sandbox while creating an embedded signing link.

When attempting to call the below post with the following body, I get a 400 Bad Request `Data Object errorCode: "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER" message: "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. A value was not found for parameter 'userName'."`

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient
Accept: application/json
Origin: https://apiexplorer.docusign.com
Content-Type: application/json

Show Base64 Bytes in Request
{
  "authenticationMethod": "none",
  "email": "myemail@example.com",
  "returnUrl": "google.com"
}
```

So it makes sense to add a userName to my recipient right? Well, yes but no. I can type in any random userName like

```
{
  "authenticationMethod": "none",
  "email": "myemail@example.com",
  "returnUrl": "google.com",
  "userName": "sdlfkjsodisdofisdofm"
}
```

And it will generate the link a successful response with an embedded link. It appears to look for email first as precedence which is what I want. What's the purpose of userName here?

Answer (score 0):

So, I think if the user is not authenticated ("none") then userName is ignored, but still is required. Which does seem like a bug, so good catch. If you want to do more testing - try v2.1, which is the latest API version we recommend you use and see if it behaves the same (most likley, but not 100% sure).
The reason userName may be needed is for example for InPersonSigner or when you use recipientAuthentication and the user needs to be correlated to a DocuSign user in some account to be able to use their auth correctly.

**Edit:** Actually, userName would be used to determine your set of signatures. Try this, set your signature and use the exact same userName. DocuSign should remember it and you won't have to do that again. If you use a different one - you would have to. So, maybe not a bug after all...
(same for the electronic consent that you only have to agree to once)